# Which facebook javascript api should I use to be able to invite and publish to wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to publish to my wall and send invites to friends stylishly.
It seems stream.publish has become depreated now.

Any other method to do this..
I would be obliged if I could have some sample codes as well.

Comment: `publish_stream` Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action in the examples section of the Facebook [JavaScript Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/).